# Reference request fundamental group of surface of genus $g$ and $n$ boundary components

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, fundamental-groups, group-presentation

Let $\Sigma_{g,n}$ be the compact, oriented surface of genus $g$ with $n$ disjoint open discs removed, where the boundary circles are called $\partial_i$. I would like to find a reference for the following group presentation of the fundamental group and the first homology group:

$\pi_1(\Sigma_{g,n},x)
=\langle \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_g,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_g, \partial_1,\ldots, \partial_n \rangle \Big/ \Big(\prod_{i=1}^g \alpha_i\beta_i\alpha_i^{-1}\beta_i^{-1}\prod_{j=1}^n \partial_j\Big) \\
H_1(\Sigma_{g,n},\mathbb{Z})
=\pi_1(\Sigma_{g,n},x)/[\pi_1(\Sigma_{g,n},x),\pi_1(\Sigma_{g,n},x)]
=\mathbb{Z}^{2g+n}\Big/ \Big(\prod_{j=1}^n \partial_j\Big)$

Does anyone know a reference? It would be nice if the reference would also include a picture with the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$. 
If $n=0$ the result can for example be found in Hatchers algebraic topology, page 51. Of course, if we know the first fact, the second one is quite clear.

Comment: The fundamental group of a surface with some positive number of punctures is free, on $2g+n-1$ punctures. (It deformation retracts onto a wedge of circles. Then you're just trying to identify how to write one boundary component in terms of the existing generators.

Comment: Do you know a reference for that? And is the claim true?

Comment: No, but here is a sketch: present $\Sigma_g$ as the quotient of a $4g$-gon by identifying sides, and then delete some points in the interior. If you delete one point, you deformation retract onto the boundary of the fundamental polygon (which you may identify as a wedge of $2g$ circles). Deleting more points, you have to add an extra arc. I suggest drawing a picture.

Comment: (Your claim looks true to me but I didn't look at the notation extremely carefully.)